# Create an immutable subclass of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, immutability

I'm designing a simple class subclassing `ArrayList<Color>`. In my application's context, this list acts as a 'reference list', returning `Color` objects following a circular and well-defined order.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public final class ColorList extends ArrayList<Color> {

    private static int colorIndex = -1;

    public ColorList() {

        this.add(Color.CYAN);
        this.add(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.add(Color.GRAY);
        this.add(Color.GREEN);
        this.add(Color.BLUE);
        this.add(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        this.add(Color.MAGENTA);
        this.add(Color.ORANGE);
        this.add(Color.PINK);
        this.add(Color.RED);
        this.add(Color.YELLOW);
    }

    //if the color chosen is not the last one, increment index and get it.
    public Color getNextColor() {
        Color color = null;
        if(colorIndex != this.size() - 1) {
            color = this.get(++colorIndex);
        }
        else {
            colorIndex = -1;
            color = this.get(++colorIndex);
        }
        return color;
    }
```

For this reason, I wanted to make this class immutable since it is intended to be a read-only list, whose content is defined when the object is first instantiated and remains constant during its whole lifetime. At the same time, I need to be able to exploit `getNextColor()` to maintain a 'circular' fashion.
**Approaches taken**

1. Return an unmodifiable reference.

   ```
   public static List<Color> getInstance(){
       return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ColorList());
   }
   ```

   The problem with this approach is that, by returning a List reference it 
   prevents me calling the `getNextColor()` method, making my class useless. 
   Casting does not solve the problem, because the underlying object is an 
   instance of `UnmodifiableRandomAccessList` and cannot be cast to `ColorList`.
2. Override methods referring to optional operations

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean add(Color c) {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("color list is read-only");
   }
   <overridding other methods such as addAll, remove...>
   ```

   As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) , some operations marked as 'optional' may or may not be implemented depending on the collection's purpose. But this would prevent me adding the colors in the first place, as I do in the constructor when the object is instantiated.
    I think I may be misunderstanding some key design aspect. Is there a way to make my class immutable, without limiting its (already basic) functionalities?
   EDIT: it is required that this class explicitly extends ArrayList for reason of backward compatibility. Hence I cannot use a wrapper class, even though I also think it would be the most correct approach.

Comment: Do you need to make it an implementation of `List`? How do you expect `ColorList` to be used? Maybe the complexity could be avoided if list functionality isn't necessary...

Comment: Why not simply use `Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(Color.CYAN, Color.DARK_GRAY, ...))`?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele it is required to extend ArrayList

Comment: If you have to extend `ArrayList`, which is mutable, then your only choice is to override methods that change the state (option 2 in your post). *Just a side note:* your `colorIndex` field will probably be a weakness in your "immutability" implementation.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele can you explain me why is that field such a "weakness"?

Comment: @kernel_panic that's because it is non-final in an object meant to be immutable. I understand that you need it for your nextColor functionality, but it will effectively defeat your objects' immutability, even if you don't have a getter for it.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I understand. Unfortunately I cannot think about any other way for providing such functionality and maintain a "full" immutability

Comment: There's one alternative I can think of: override the `iterator()` method and give your own implementation of `Iterator<Color>`, which always returns `true` for `hasNext` and has the `index` field. That way, you will remove the mutable state from `ColorList` and put it into your Iterable class, of which you will create an instance each time `colorIterator.iterator()` is called.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele sounds like a nice solution. Honestly I did not think to exploit the built in Iterator to obtain the functionality I want. I will try and go for it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the contents of the List to be immutable, then your constructor kind of works, only you should be calling `super.add(...)` instead of `this.add(...)`; doing so would mean that your overrides on `add(...)` would be sensible to protect the list from outside interference, while allowing the constructor to initialise the object for you.

Your question is unclear, but if you also want to prevent direct access to objects within the List, you can also obviously override `get(...)` and other methods as appropriate - though if you do, then your `getNextColor(...)` method should call `super.get(...)` rather than `this.get(...)`.

Finally, you probably don't need the `colors` member variable, because you're extending a List - no point nesting another List within it.

Comment: Apologize for the unclarity, if you mind to point out what should be explained better I will edit accordingly

Comment: No problem, I only meant unclear in the requirements you have been given - do you need to prevent direct access to the array elements. Also, as an afterthought, if this is school/college work, you may be marked down slightly for re-inventing the wheel (ArrayList extends AbstractList, which implements Iterable, and provides a "next(...)" method).

Answer (score 2):

Think in your case it's better to use composition not inheritance. In this case you just don't expose methods which can modify a list of colors.

Here is an example code

```
public final class ColorList {
    private final Color[] values;
    private int colorIndex;

    public ColorList(Color... colors) {
        this.values = colors;
    }

    public Color getNextColor() {
        if (colorIndex == values.length) colorIndex = 0;

        return values[colorIndex++];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColorList cl = new ColorList(Color.CYAN, Color.YELLOW, Color.WHITE);

        System.out.println(cl.getNextColor());
        System.out.println(cl.getNextColor());
        System.out.println(cl.getNextColor());
        System.out.println(cl.getNextColor());
    }
}
```

There are few moments worth to mention in source code you provided:

- colorIndex variable is static so it shared between all instances of ColorList class. If more that one instance invoke getNextColor() that the result will be inconsistent. Maybe you have an idea to create Singleton class so only one instance of it is possible?
- the list of colors in your code is always the same and known at compile time so it's impossible to create ColorList instance with different set of colors. Is that what supposed to be?

Comment: My fault, previously I implemented such class as a Singleton and being told I couldn't due to design restrictions, and forgot to remove 'static' prior posting the code. A composition was the solution I had thought in the first place, sadly for compatibilty with extenal code I have been told to design a class which specifically extends ArrayList, but is immutable. And yes, the color are supposed to be always the same (at least for now), so I simply hardcoded them. Nice solution though, and interesting the choice of use a constructor with variable-length args